# Can any one give me some idea how to write a test class for the below mentioned batch class

Tags: unit-test

```
global class batchorgUpdate implements Database.Batchable<sObject> {
    global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC) {
        String query = 'SELECT Id,Name, Appraisal__c,Designation__c,Employee_Name__c,Grade__c,  Salary_Scale__c FROM Organization__c';
        return Database.getQueryLocator(query);
    }  
    global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<Organization__c> org) {
             for(Organization__c r : org)
          {
               if(r.Salary_Scale__c==10000)
              {
                     r.Grade__c='C';
                     r.Designation__c='JD';
              }
               if(r.Appraisal__c==10 &&  r.Designation__c=='JD' && r.Salary_Scale__c==10000)
              {
                      r.Grade__c='C+';
                      r.Salary_Scale__c=11000;
              }    
               if(r.Appraisal__c==10 &&  r.Designation__c=='JD' && r.Salary_Scale__c==11000)
              {
                      r.Grade__c='B';
                      r.Salary_Scale__c=12000;
              }    
                if(r.Salary_Scale__c==20000)
              {
                      r.Grade__c='A';
                      r.Designation__c='SD';
                      r.Appraisal__c=null;
              }        
          }
         update org;
    } 
    global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC) {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your test insert a small number of `Organization__c` objects with field values that match the various cases in your code.

Then run your `Batchable` ensuring that the `execute` method is only called once (a limitation in tests) by specifing a batch size that is greater than the number of `Organization__c` objects you inserted:

```
Test.startTest();
Database.executeBatch(new batchorgUpdate(), 200);
Test.stopTest();
```

The [Test.stopTest documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_test.htm#apex_System_Test_stopTest) explains that:

> All asynchronous calls made after the startTest method are collected
>   by the system. When stopTest is executed, all asynchronous processes
>   are run synchronously.

Then re-query the `Organization__c` objects and [assert](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_system.htm#apex_System_System_assertEquals) that the expected changes have been made.